# Why won't this mod_rewrite rule work (via .htaccess one specific url to another)

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

RewriteRule ^/tag/term$ /tag/term-expanded-here [R]

Comment: What's the request you're trying to match?

Answer (score 0):

If you’re [using mod_rewrite in a .htaccess file](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule), you need to remove the path prefix from the pattern:

> When using the rewrite engine in .htaccess files the per-directory prefix (which always is the same for a specific directory) is automatically *removed* for the pattern matching and automatically *added* after the substitution has been done.

In case of the .htaccess file in the document root directory it’s the leading `/`:

```
RewriteRule ^tag/term$ /tag/term-expanded-here [R]
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work. The request I'm trying to match is ^tag/term$ and rewrite it as /tag/term-expanded-here